# mapred-site.xml file not present in Hadoop 2.7.0

Tags: 14.04, hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. There is no *mapred-site.xml* file in the `hadoop-2.7.0/etc/hadoop` directory. But there is a file *mapred-site.xml.template* in that directory. Are both files the same or is mapred-site.xml file missing? The *hadoop-env.sh* and *core-site.xml* files are present in the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rename the `mapred-site.xml.template` file to `mapred-site.xml`.
(in `hadoop-2.7.0/etc/hadoop`)

For this, you can use:

```
mv mapred-site.xml.template mapred-site.xml
```

and then make changes in the configuration file `mapred-site.xml` as required.